# Code Fail" TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [0.5] of <class 'float'

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_bt = pd.DataFrame({'N' : range(1, 241 ,1)})

df_bt= pd.merge(df_bt,rates,how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)

    for i in range(0, 30):
        df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates1'] = df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates']
    for i in range(29, 120):
                df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates1'] = df_bt.loc[29, 'Rates']   
    df_bt['mod'] = df_bt['N'].mod(2)

    df_bt.loc[0, 'Rates2'] = df_bt.loc[0, 'Rates1']
    for i in range(0, len(df_bt['N'])):
        if df_bt.loc[i, 'mod'] == 0:
            df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates2'] = df_bt.loc[((i/2)),'Rates1']
    for i in range(1, len(df_bt['N'])):
        if df_bt.loc[i, 'mod'] == 1:
            df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates2'] = (df_bt.loc[(i-1), 'Rates2'] + df_bt.loc[(i+1), 'Rates2'])/2
```

Error:

> Code Failing: TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [0.5] of <class 'float'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in these lines:

```
    if df_bt.loc[i, 'mod'] == 0:
            df_bt.loc[i, 'Rates2'] = df_bt.loc[((i/2)),'Rates1']
```

though you have checked mod == 0, but that modulo is for number N, not for index i. So for i which are odd number, you still get float values, that is why the bug.